# Create dcc.Dropdown values Dynamically with Python Function

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am creating a search application with Dash by Plotly. I have a main search function for that creates a dataframe for the whole application that is defined as:

```
def search(term):
    with index.searcher() as searcher:
        parser = QueryParser("content", index.schema)
        myquery = parser.parse(term)
        results = searcher.search(myquery, limit=None)
        print("Documents Containing ", term, ": ", len(results), "\n")
        df = pd.DataFrame([i['date'], i['site'], i['system'], i['ticket'], i.score, i['level'], i['first'], i['last'], i['department'], \
                               i['detect'], i['code'],i['content'], i['description'], i['owner'], i['ownerGroup'], i['docId']] for i in results)
        df.columns=['Reported Date', 'Site', 'System','Ticket ID', 'Score', 'Level', 'First', 'Last', 'Department',  \
                        'Detection', 'Code', 'Content', 'Description', 'Owner', 'Owner Group', 'Document ID']  
    return df
```

I want users to be able to filter down search results with filters built into `dcc.Dropdown`. A couple of them can be hard-coded like so:

```
dcc.Dropdown(
                         id='siteFilter',
                         options=[
                                  {'label': 'ABC', 'value': 'ABC'},
                                  {'label': 'DEF', 'value': 'DEF'},
                                  {'label': 'HIJ', 'value': 'HIJ'},
                                  {'label': 'LMO', 'value': 'LMO'}
                                  ],
                          value=['ABC', 'DEF', 'HIJ', 'LMO'],
                                            multi=True
```

However, some of the fields I want to filter on contain many options for a search and cannot be hard-coded. I can get the options to work. However, my application will not apply the filter changing when a user changes values. So, I have in my `app.layout`:

```
        html.Div(dbc.Row([dbc.Col([
                            html.Label(["System Filter", 
                                    dcc.Dropdown(
                                            id='systemFilter',
                                            options='options',
                                            value='All',
                                            multi=True,
                                            )
                                    ])
                                    ], width = 5)
                                    ]))
```

In my callback, I have tried several different options/combos of Outputs and States to achieve this with no luck. Callback:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='outTable', component_property='data'),
     Output(component_id='outTable', component_property='columns'),
     Output(component_id='commonWords', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='options'),
     #Output(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='value')
     ],
    [Input(component_id='button', component_property='n_clicks')],
    [State('searchId', 'value'),
    State('siteFilter', 'value'),
    State('detectFilter', 'value'),
    State('levelFilter', 'value'),
    State('codeFilter', 'value'),
    #State(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='value')
    ])


def tableCreate(n_clicks, searchId, siteFilter, detectFilter, levelFilter, codeFilter):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        searchFrame = search(searchId)
        
        ###################### System Filter #######################################
        #print('HERE DLKFSJSLDFKJSLDKJFJLKFDSJLDSKF')
        #print(searchFrame['System'].unique())
        #global optionsArray
        optionsArray = searchFrame['System'].unique()
        optionsArray = optionsArray.tolist()
        print('Test')
        print(optionsArray)
        print('Test')
        system_filter_options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in optionsArray]
        systemFilter = optionsArray
        
        searchFrame = searchFrame[searchFrame['System'].isin(systemFilter)]

# Bunch of other code
        searchFrame = searchFrame.drop(columns=['ContentNoStop'])
        columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in searchFrame.columns]
        data = searchFrame.to_dict(orient='records')    
    
        return data, columns, wordComponent, system_filter_options #, systemFilter
    else:
        return dash.no_update, dash.no_update, dash.no_update, dash.no_update
```

Essentially, one of 2 things happens. 1) The values return blank because they are not defined or 2) the options continually override the updated value parameter which I know is caused by the line `systemFilter = optionsArray` but I cannot seem to figure out a work around for this.

Here is an example image. I would like the results to populate all, but when a user filters by system and only selects a few, all my graphs and tables should update. But everytime, it does not seem to catch that. What am I missing here? How can the dcc.Dropdown selections be applied as a filter dynamically? I cannot and do not want to hard-code all the options

[image]

Easier reproduceable example:

I would like the dropdowns options to filter the table. If dog is selected, the table only shows dog.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP]


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
server = app.server

def createTable(): 
    df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0],
                   'system': ['falcon', 'dog', 'spider', 'fish']},
                  index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
    
    return df

app.layout =  html.Div([
        html.Button('Submit and Refresh', id='button', n_clicks=0, className='btn btn-primary'),
        dbc.Row([dbc.Col([
                            html.Label(["System Filter", 
                                    dcc.Dropdown(
                                            id='systemFilter',
                                            options='options',
                                            value='All',
                                            multi=True,
                                            )
                                    ])
                                    ], width = 5)
                ]),
        html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(style_cell={
                                            'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                            'height': 'auto',
                                            'textAlign': 'left'
                                            }, 
                            fill_width=False,
                            id='outTable',
                            sort_action="native",
                            sort_mode="multi",
                            column_selectable="single",
                            row_deletable=True,

                            )
                        ],
                        
                )                ])
                     


@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='outTable', component_property='data'),
     Output(component_id='outTable', component_property='columns'),

     Output(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='options'),
     #Output(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='value')
     ],
    [Input(component_id='button', component_property='n_clicks')],
    [
    State(component_id='systemFilter', component_property='value')
    ])


def tableCreate(n_clicks, systemFilter):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        searchFrame = createTable()
            

        optionsArray = searchFrame['system'].unique()
        optionsArray = optionsArray.tolist()
        print('Test')
        print(optionsArray)
        print('Test')
        system_filter_options = [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in optionsArray]
        systemFilter = optionsArray
        
        searchFrame = searchFrame[searchFrame['system'].isin(systemFilter)]
        
        columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in searchFrame.columns]
        data = searchFrame.to_dict(orient='records')    
        
        return data, columns, system_filter_options#, systemFilter
                                        
                                    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: Would you consider editing your function with a [mcve]? I mean a very minimal example in order to design the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: @rpanai Thank you for the response. See the simpler example I added. I would like the dropdown to update the table with just what is selected.